# Amplifying a decaying signal to a signal of uniform amplitude

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design

What is the best way, in hardware, to amplify a decaying signal to a signal of uniform amplitude, as shown in the picture below? Does this amplification scheme have a name? I'm working in the audio range.

[image: mystery amplifier]

Comment: *Automatic gain control (AGC)* is one possible name for this.  What's the nature of the signal?  What causes the decay?

Comment: The signal is audio from a guitar. I will look up AGC. Thank you.

Comment: Ah ha! so they make AGC ICs that work in the audio range. I knew all I needed was a google search term. many thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a compressor/sustainer? This is a guitar pedal you can buy.

Comment: Possible search term : ADSR circuit : (Attack/Decay/Sustain/Release), also common in analog synthesisers.

Comment: I need to "remove the envelope" if that makes sense. Or rather, give the signal a rectangular envelope. I need to do this to condition it for an FFT so the higher harmonics are more visible. Seems to me there would be a standard implementation of this type of amplifier. Yes, its similar to a compressor set a certain way, and has things in common with an ADSR but neither of those things are very practical. I left the context out of my original post which was a mistake but oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You're reinventing the guitar compressor (but that's fine).

As the commenters have noted it's an automatic gain control circuit that's required and they're used for many applications particularly to limit the signal level where exceeding the maximum will cause distortion by clipping of the audio.

You will come across terms such as:

- Attack: how quickly the compressing action ramps up.
- Sustain: the level above which compression occurs.
- Release: how quickly the compressing action is released as the input signal level reduces.
- S/N (signal to noise). Since the effect of compression is that high signal levels are reduced it stands to reason that in quiet passages the background noise will be much more noticable.
- Pumping: a (usually) unwanted effect of rapid changes of level caused by low frequency signal - see below.

Most of these devices work by converting the input signal into a DC voltage and using this to control the gain of an amplifier stage. Increasing control voltage results in lower gain. Compromises have to be made between rapid response to sudden changes in level - very significant in guitar as the strings have very high attack when plucked - and not so rapid that every cycle of a bass note causes the gain to change.

Have fun.